# Apache Spark mapPartitionsWithIndex

Tags: java, mapreduce, apache-spark

Can someone give example of correct usage of mapPartitionsWithIndex in Java? I've found a lot of Scala examples, but there is lack of Java ones.
Is my understanding correct that separate partitions will be handled by separate nodes when using this function.

I am getting the following error

```
method mapPartitionsWithIndex in class JavaRDD<T> cannot be applied to given types;
    JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.textFile(filename).mapPartitionsWithIndex
    required: Function2<Integer,Iterator<String>,Iterator<R>>,boolean
    found: <anonymous Function2<Integer,Iterator<String>,Iterator<JavaRDD<String>>>>
```

When doing

```
JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.textFile(filename).mapPartitionsWithIndex(
    new Function2<Integer, Iterator<String>, Iterator<JavaRDD<String>> >() {

    @Override
    public Iterator<JavaRDD<String>> call(Integer ind, String s) {
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you're getting at. What have you tried? what didn't work? The Java API is straightforwardly analogous to the Scala API in the same way as other operations. Partitions will be handled by different tasks which may or may not be on different machines since your data partitions may or may not live on different machines.

Comment: Well, I have no Scala knowledge, so it is hard for me to read Scala code. I simply need Java example of Function2 implementation that is to be passed into mapPartitionsWithIndex. I followed the only found example, but got build errors.

Comment: Why not post the error you are asking about then?

Comment: I have updated initial question with the error I am getting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the code I use to remove the first line of a csv file:

```
JavaRDD<String> rawInputRdd = sparkContext.textFile(dataFile);

Function2 removeHeader= new Function2<Integer, Iterator<String>, Iterator<String>>(){
    @Override
    public Iterator<String> call(Integer ind, Iterator<String> iterator) throws Exception {
        if(ind==0 && iterator.hasNext()){
            iterator.next();
            return iterator;
        }else
            return iterator;
    }
};
JavaRDD<String> inputRdd = rawInputRdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(removeHeader, false);
```

Comment: Awesome! Helped me get this one right: [Apache Spark Function2, not getting declaration right](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38468390/3255525)

Comment: This will remove the first row in the partition right, not within the file?

Comment: Right. Just remove the line in the live partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `mapPartitionsWithIndex` without using an [anonymous function code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28938316/15510171).

```
   JavaRDD<String> rawInputRdd = sparkContext.textFile(dataFile);

    JavaRDD<String> inputRdd = rawInputRdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((ind, iterator) -> {
      if (ind == 0 && iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
        return iterator;
      } else
        return iterator;
    }, false);
```