# Apache Spark Function2, not getting declaration right

Tags: java, apache-spark, map-function

*(This is based on trying to map a Integer RDD to a TholdDropResult RDD, but we need to initialize a single SparkDoDrop to generate all the (10^8) TholdDropResults, hence the use of [mapPartitionsWithIndex](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala), the only flavor in Java of mapPartition that will provide the type of function we need, methinks.)*

Question: I am getting an error using `org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2`

I am not able to figure out how to work the "boolean" into a `new Function2`

When I try this code, scroll right to see the `new Function2` declaration that appears to be giving me trouble (added builder-style formatting from answer):

```
JavaRDD<TholdDropResult> dropResultsN = dataSetN.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
                                      new Function2<Integer, 
                                      Iterator<Integer>, 
                                      Iterator<TholdDropResult>>(){

        @Override
        public Iterator<TholdDropResult> call(Integer partitionID, Iterator<Integer> integerIterator) throws Exception {
            //
            SparkDoDrop standin = makeNewSparkDoDrop();
            standin.initializeLI();
            List<TholdDropResult> rddToReturn = new ArrayList<>();
            while (integerIterator.hasNext()){
                rddToReturn.add(standin.call(integerIterator.next()));
            }
            return rddToReturn.iterator();

        }});
    dropResultsN.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
```

Here's the full error when I run `gradle build`:

```
JavaRDD<TholdDropResult> dropResultsN = dataSetN.mapPartitionsWithIndex(new Function2<Integer, Iterator<Integer>, Iterator<TholdDropResult>>(){
required: Function2<Integer,Iterator<Integer>,Iterator<R>>,boolean
  found: <anonymous Function2<Integer,Iterator<Integer>,Iterator<TholdDropResult>>>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where R,T,This are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>mapPartitionsWithIndex(Function2<Integer,Iterator<T>,Iterator<R>>,boolean)
    T extends Object declared in class AbstractJavaRDDLike
    This extends JavaRDDLike<T,This> declared in class AbstractJavaRDDLike
```

**When I try to place the Boolean arg in there like so:
`new Function2<Integer, Iterator<Integer>, Iterator<TholdDropResult>, Boolean>()`
I get an error:**

```
error: wrong number of type arguments; required 3
            JavaRDD<TholdDropResult> dropResultsN = dataSetN.mapPartitionsWithIndex(new Function2<Integer, Iterator<Integer>, Iterator<TholdDropResult>, Boolean>(){
```

Finally if I use `boolean` instead of `Boolean` I get another error:

```
error: unexpected type
            JavaRDD<TholdDropResult> dropResultsN = dataSetN.mapPartitionsWithIndex(new Function2<Integer, Iterator<Integer>, Iterator<TholdDropResult>, boolean>(){
                                                                                                                                                         ^
  required: reference
  found:    boolean

error: wrong number of type arguments; required 3
            JavaRDD<TholdDropResult> dropResultsN = dataSetN.mapPartitionsWithIndex(new Function2<Integer, Iterator<Integer>, Iterator<TholdDropResult>, boolean>(){
```

Comment: And FWIW the whole reason for this approach is that the line `standin.initializeLI();` creates a rather large object we don't want to serialize, we want Spark to create this object out on the executor.

Answer (score 1):

You need the close the `Function2` with an additional `>` before the `Boolean`:

```
JavaRDD<TholdDropResult> dropResultsN =
   dataSetN.mapPartitionsWithIndex(new Function2<Integer, 
                                                 Iterator<Integer>,
                                                 Iterator<TholdDropResult>>, Boolean>
```

The signature of `mapPartitionsWithIndex` looks like this:

```
<R> JavaRDD<R> mapPartitionsWithIndex(Function2<java.lang.Integer,
                                                java.util.Iterator<T>,
                                                java.util.Iterator<R>> f,
                                                boolean preservesPartitioning)
```

The `Function2` takes an `Integer` and a `Iterator<T>` and returns an `Iterator<R>`. The `boolean` expected is a parameter not defined inside the `Function2`.

Comment: I am going to +1 and accept, in part for reminding me of the much better formatting I should use. At the same time that didn't fix it. I get _unexpected token_, an error on the @Override and more when I use `dataSetN.mapPartitionsWithIndex(new Function2<Integer,
                                                                                        Iterator<Integer>,
                                                                                        Iterator<TholdDropResult>>, boolean>(){`

Comment: I would use a foreachPartition() but I need this to return a RDD of TholdDropResult, I don't believe foreachPartition allows any function other than VoidFunction. hmmmm

Comment: I got it, see my answer and THANKS for pointing me in the right direction, also help from this answer to [Apache Spark mapPartitionsWithIndex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28938316/3255525)

Answer (score 0):

This works, not sure why, but separating out the Function2 did the trick (of course I have not compiled and run yet :)

```
        Function2 makeLIThenDropResults = new Function2<Integer,
                                                        Iterator<Integer>,
                                                        Iterator<TholdDropResult>>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<TholdDropResult> call(Integer partitionID, Iterator<Integer> integerIterator) throws Exception {
                SparkDoDrop standin = makeNewSparkDoDrop();

                standin.initializeLI();
                List<TholdDropResult> rddToReturn = new ArrayList<>();
                while (integerIterator.hasNext()){
                    rddToReturn.add(standin.call(integerIterator.next()));
                }
                return rddToReturn.iterator();
            }
        };

        // now make the RDD of subset of N
        // setup bogus arrays of size N for parallelize to lead to dropResultsN
        JavaRDD<TholdDropResult> dropResultsN = dataSetN.mapPartitionsWithIndex(makeLIThenDropResults, true);
```

(hat tip to [this answer on Apache Spark mapPartitionsWithIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28938316/3255525))